# Heroku pre-recieve hook declined, failed to push some refs to [app-url] with MERN stack

Tags: node.js, github, heroku

**The issue**

> ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined) error:
> failed to push some refs to
> 'https://git.heroku.com/young-lake-89044.git'

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AIL1c-cJM0&t=4s&ab_channel=TheFullStackJunkie) and I am doing exactly as he says yet I run into this error message.

My steps:

1. git remote (to check the remote repo is there)
2. git add .
3. git push heroku

**My application**

I am using the MERN stack.

My project folder system is as follows:

```
Project
 - frontend
 - backend
```

The backend holds the server.js script. On my project, it is called the app.js script.

Here is the app.js for /backend:

```
// app.js

const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const path = require('path');
var cors = require('cors');

// routes
const articles = require('./routes/api/articles');

const app = express();

// Connect Database
connectDB();

// cors
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

//app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello world!'));

// use Routes
app.use('/api/articles', articles);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'frontend', 'build')));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'));
    })
} else {
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('API Running');
    });
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Here is the package.json file which has the heroku-postbuild script:

```
{
  "name": "mern_a_to_z",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "app": "nodemon app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix ../frontend&&npm run build --prefix frontend"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/nurislam03/MERN_A_to_Z.git"
  },
  "author": "Nur Islam",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nurislam03/MERN_A_to_Z/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/nurislam03/MERN_A_to_Z#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.11",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.15",
    "validation": "0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

And lastly my Procfile which sits inside of backend:

```
web: node app.js
```

**Full Error Output**

> ```
> PS C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\CISE-Team-1> git push heroku
> Enumerating objects: 32838, done.
> Counting objects: 100% (32838/32838), done.
> Delta compression using up to 8 threads
> Compressing objects: 100% (25047/25047), done.
> Writing objects: 100% (32838/32838), 37.24 MiB | 48.00 KiB/s, done.
> Total 32838 (delta > 6984), reused 30707 (delta 6475)
> remote: Compressing source files... done.
> remote: Building source:
> remote:
> remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
> remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
> remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
> remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku
>                                 cannot detect the buildpack to use
>                                 for this application automatically.
> remote:                         See
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
> remote:
> remote:  !   Push failed
> remote:  !
> remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code
> has already been built: a5ffe033316042c0575cd8e67d548460f8607950
> remote:  !
> remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from
>            source code with version 5ffe033316042c0575cd8e67d548460f8607950
> remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior
>            is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
> remote:  !
> remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying
>            via git you must run:
> remote:  !
> remote:  !    git push heroku <branchname>:main
> remote:  !
> remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
> remote:  !  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
> remote:
> remote: Verifying deploy...
> remote:
> remote: !       Push rejected to young-lake-89044.
> remote: To https://git.heroku.com/young-lake-89044.git
>  ! [remote rejected]  main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/young-lake-89044.git'
> ```

I do not believe that I was getting the same version error the first time I ran the push command.

Lastly, my application works perfectly on its own.

**What I have tried**

1. git push heroku master
2. git push heroku main
3. git push heroku
4. Deleted package-lock.json in backend

I also tried:

1. git init
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "First commit"
4. heroku create
5. git push heroku master

Then I got errors complaining about no master branch. So I had to do:

1. git push heroku main:master

Which brought me back to square one, with the exact same error.

So I then tried:

1. git commit -m dummy --allow-empty

Then, once again the same error. I have been trying to simply deploy for over 5 hours now searching through every single stack overflow forum I could find.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you check out both https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version as advised?

Comment: Thank you for that! I already read the duplicate-build-version doc but must have missed the buildpacks. After specifying the buildpack to be nodejs, it threw an error saying it could not find pacakge.json in the root directory. I re-arranged my directory so that everything it needed was on the highest level and it stopped throwing the error. Now it just goes back to the same pre-recieve hook declined error.

Comment: It got so much further though. It now is throwing a few errors such as react-scripts permission denied and just says it failed at frontend@0.1.0 so I will try and debug that now!

Comment: Note that the pre-receive hook is what makes this get handled by Heroku. The `remote:` lines in Git output are coming from Heroku: Git is just the messenger, and has no idea what's going on here.

Comment: After many hours of trying every possible thing, I managed to get it to deploy to Heroku. Such a relief! The very first `npm ERR`, which was a few lines before the `permission denied` error, said `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE.`. What I did was deleted the frontend and the backend node_modules folder and did `npm install` in both folders. After doing that, I ran into a `NO DISK SPACE` error in the frontend. So, I checked and my drive was completely full so I had to delete quite a few things. After that, I tried to push from my current branch to Heroku's main and it worked perfectly.

Comment: So, if it was not for that buildpacks article you linked, I would not have managed to get the initial error which was the fact that for node.js buildpacks you need the package.json for the server to be in the root folder. After that I then got the ELIFECYCLE, which once solved my application got deployed to Heroku!